# Definition of a limit using epsilon delta

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I am a little confused regarding the definition of a limit using $\varepsilon$,$\delta$.First of all I would like to know if the full understanding of the limit idea requires any prior knowledge about $\varepsilon ,\delta$ or is it a notion that first appears in the definition of limits.Second I am confused about what epsilon depicts. Does it depict the total of all positive real numbers? In addition to that why is $\delta $ expressed as a function of $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: This is very vague.  I suggest studying the definition.

Comment: What is the definition of it?

Comment: Where did you see the idea of $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs that you didn't also see a definition go along with it?

Comment: @ Brian Tung You mean definition the one that says that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that ... ?

Comment: The basic idea behind $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ is that as $x$ gets closer and closer to $a$, $f(x)$ should get closer and closer to $L$. The way we define that can be thought of as a kind of challenge: You think the limit is $L$? Well, if I give you an error margin around $L$, you should be able to come up with window around $a$ so that every value of $f(x)$ within that window (other than $f(a)$ itself) is guaranteed to fall in the error margin around $L$. That's the idea: $\varepsilon$ is the error margin, and $\delta$ is the (half-)width of the window.

Comment: If that's not enough, you'll have to be more specific about what you don't understand. Make sure you put this detail in your original question, not as a comment response. (While you're at it, you should probably put your understanding of the definition in the post, too.)

Comment: @Brian Tung Is it implied in the definition of a limit that $\delta$ is considered to be infinitesimal?

Comment: I'm not Brian, but no. The idea is that for *any* positive $\epsilon$, you can choose a positive $\delta$ that works. In particular, this has to hold for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$, but it's never infinitesimal (indeed the notion of a limit is for precisely the purpose of avoiding infinitesimals).

Comment: No. I really recommend that you find the definition, read through it, think about it for some time, and then come back and tell us what you can't understand about it. That's the best use of everyone's time, I think.

Comment: I think of $\epsilon$ as an error term which bounds the precision you're looking for and the $\delta$ is a function of $\epsilon$ that gives me bounds on the input that will give me the desired bounds on the output. This is mostly motivated by the role limits play in defining continuous functions but it's proven a useful way to build intuition.